# I should be getting [[1,0],[0,0]] why am I getting [[1,0],[1,0]]?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, shallow-copy

So I have an empty array and and I am adding two arrays each with two elements using a for loop. So when I update my first element in the first array, my second array first element also gets updated. What is the issue ? Please help.

```
let matrix = []
let point = [0, 0]

for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++){
    matrix.push(point)
}

matrix[0][0] = 1

console.log(matrix)
```

Comment: `point` is both in `matrix[0]` AND `matrix[1]` - try `matrix.push([...point])`

Comment: array is a non-primitive data type.

Comment: More specifically objects (which includes arrays) is a *reference type*. When you pass/assign an object the destination gets passed a *reference* to the value, not a copy of the value.